# How to use geoserver + postgresql online?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, geoserver

Currently, My project is running on digital ocean server. And the database which I have been using is MySQL.

I want to find shortest path using **postgresql + geoserver.**

So I did it successfully on my localhost (Machine), Now I want to deploy postgresql + geoserver online so I try alot and didnot get any success.
Plz guide me and give me a solution for this problem.

And also brief me the best hosting server to host my application.

Comment: This question may require substantial editing since you haven't provided any clear examples of finding the shortest path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try AcuGIS hosting. It provides GeoServer hosting with postgresql including postgis extension. It also includes pgRouting services.
https://www.acugis.com/geoserver-hosting.htm